# sending images from gallery

Tags: android

we are doing a chatting application in android 2.3.3. We want to send images from gallery from one emulator to other using socket programming.We are new to android and not finding how to do it. Any help in this regard will be appreciable.
Thanks in advance

Comment: A search might reveal a lot of sample code for socket implementations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057417/socket-connection-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get an image from gallery using action pick, as below:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
               android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE);
```

this would allow you to start gallery application to pick a photo:
in OnActivityResult you would receive a uri of the photo:

process this uri to get byte array from this:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) { 
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent); 

    switch(requestCode) { 
    case REQ_CODE_PICK_IMAGE:
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
            Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();


            Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);

            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

            //Open a Socket Connection to send photo

            Socket socket=new Socket("ip", portNo);
            OutputStream os=socket.getOutputStream();
            os.write(byteArray);
            os.flush();

            //Read response by getting input stream from socket.

        }
    }
}
```